# php7 didnt run or detect the PDO with ubuntu 16.04 and laravel V:5.1.35 and V:5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu, pdo

Already i installed php7 and all the plugings and coposer for run laravel, but when go to a new project and wrote "laravel new blog" or "php artizan" appear the following error:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll' -
>   /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:
>   require(/home/fabio/Documentos/Digital_Dreams/appintervalo/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/fabio/Documentos/Digital_Dreams/appintervalo/bootstrap/autoload.php
>   on line 17 PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/fabio/Documentos/Digital_Dreams/appintervalo/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /home/fabio/Documentos/Digital_Dreams/appintervalo/bootstrap/autoload.php
>   on line 17

i followed the following page for install php, mysql:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

i followed the following page for install laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#server-requirements

NOTE:The requeriments for laravel 5.1 is the same, u could verifided the version documentacion on the top of the page.

if somebady knows the answer, thanks.

Comment: for the phpinfo() of my machine download the following: [phpinfo().html](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5-G62NLE_zwakUwZ2xkbEpwUUk)

Comment: I bet, You are just missing `php7-pdo` extension. `sudo apt-get install php7-pdo` should fix this problem.